# Python - haversine distance between 2 dataframes and allocate the corresponding Limit to loc with min distance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, distance

I have 2 dataframes:

1. df_exposure (>300k rows)

```
    ID  Limit   Lat Lon
0   1   49  21.066107   121.930200
1   2   49  20.932773   121.913533
2   3   49  20.932773   121.921867
3   4   49  20.924440   121.930200
4   5   49  20.899440   121.905200
```

from df_exposure i extract

```
lat_loc = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lat']
lon_loc = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lon']
```

2. df (3k rows):

```
Lat Lon Limit
0   4.125   116.125 0.0
1   4.375   116.125 0.0
2   4.625   116.125 0.0
3   4.875   116.125 0.0
4   5.125   116.125 0.0
```

And this is the haversine function:

```
def haversine(lat2, lon2, lat1, lon1):
    
    lat1_ = lat1 * np.pi / 180
    lat2_ = lat2 * np.pi / 180
    lon1_ = lon1 * np.pi / 180
    lon2_ = lon2 * np.pi / 180
     
    a = (np.sin((lat2_ - lat1_) / 2)**2) + (np.sin((lon2_ - lon1_) / 2)**2) * np.cos(lat1_) * np.cos(lat2_)
    dist = 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

    return dist
```

Essentially, the df is a subset of df_exposure with bigger grid size and I would like to get the get the distance between all locations in df against each location (row) of lat long in df_exposure to find the minimum distance and allocate the Limit in the corresponding df_exposure row to location in df with smallest distance and this will be iterative on each location in df_exposure until all locations are calculated.

This is how currently it is done but it takes a very long time because of the size of df_exposure (>300k rows)

```
for i in range(len(lat_loc)):

    r = haversine(df.loc[:, 'Lat'], df.loc[:, 'Lon'], lat_loc[i], lon_loc[i])
    dist = r.min() # find minimum distance
    df.loc[list(r).index(dist), 'Limit'] = df.loc[list(r).index(dist), 'Limit'] + df_exposure.loc[i, 'Limit']
```

I would appreciate some suggestion to improve the current code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go in order. I have created dataframes with the specified dimensions. Here is the runtime of your implementation:

```py
import time

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


EXPOSURE_SIZE = 300_000
DF_SIZE = 3000

df_exposure = pd.DataFrame({'Limit': np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(EXPOSURE_SIZE,)),
                            'Lat': np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=EXPOSURE_SIZE),
                            'Lon': np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=EXPOSURE_SIZE)})

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Limit': np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(DF_SIZE,)),
     'Lat': np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=DF_SIZE),
     'Lon': np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=DF_SIZE)})


def haversine(lat2, lon2, lat1, lon1):
    lat1_ = lat1 * np.pi / 180
    lat2_ = lat2 * np.pi / 180
    lon1_ = lon1 * np.pi / 180
    lon2_ = lon2 * np.pi / 180

    a = (np.sin((lat2_ - lat1_) / 2) ** 2) + (np.sin((lon2_ - lon1_) / 2) ** 2) * np.cos(lat1_) * np.cos(lat2_)
    dist = 2 * 6371 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

    return dist


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lat_loc = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lat']
    lon_loc = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lon']

    start = time.monotonic()
    for i in range(len(lat_loc)):
        r = haversine(df.loc[:, 'Lat'], df.loc[:, 'Lon'], lat_loc[i], lon_loc[i])
        dist = r.min()  # find minimum distance
        df.loc[list(r).index(dist), 'Limit'] = df.loc[list(r).index(dist), 'Limit'] + df_exposure.loc[i, 'Limit']
    print(f'with for loop and series time took: {time.monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
```

```
Out:
     with for loop and series time took: 456.3 s.
```

You should understand that in this case you are passing `lat` and `lon` as a `pd.Series` to the `haversine`  function. With that, your function is vectorized. Let's pass the coordinates as `numpy` arrays

```py
lon = df['Lon'].values
lat = df['Lat'].values

start = time.monotonic()
    for i in range(len(lat_loc)):
        r = haversine(lat, lon, lat_loc[i], lon_loc[i])
        df.iloc[np.argmin(r), 0] = df.iloc[np.argmin(r), 0] + df_exposure.iloc[i, 0]
    print(f'with for loop and ndarray time took: {time.monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
```

```
Out:
     with for loop and ndarray time took: 62.4 s.
```

Wow! Speedup is ~ 7 time.

Let's try to use V.M answer and use the `DistanceMetric` class from  `sklearn.metrics` module:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import DistanceMetric

distance = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

lat1 = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lat']
lon1 = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lon']

lat2 = df.loc[:, 'Lat']
lon2 = df.loc[:, 'Lon']
start = time.monotonic()
res = (6371 * distance.pairwise((np.array([lat1, lon1]) * np.pi / 180).T,
                                     (np.array([lat2, lon2]) * np.pi / 180).T)).argmin(axis=1)
print(f'with sklearn pairwise distance time took: {time.monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
```

```
Out: 
    with sklearn pairwise distance time took: 45.6 s.
```

Even better! Speed-up is ~ 10 time

But what if the logic inside the loop is moved to a new function and the `apply` methods are used?

```py
def foo(row, lat, lon):
    """
    row: row of DataFrame
    lat: ndarray with latitude
    lon: ndarray with longitude
    """
    r = haversine(lat, lon, row[1], row[2])
    return r.argmin()

start = time.monotonic()
res = df_exposure.apply(foo, raw=True, axis=1, args=(lat, lon))
print(f'synchronous apply time took: {time.monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
```

```
Out:
    synchronous apply time took: 32.4 s.
```

Wow! It's even faster.

Can we speed up our calculations even more? Yes! If we remember that `pandas` always runs on one core of your `CPU`. We need to parallelize the best of the received ways. This can easily be done with [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/)

```py
#pip install parallel-pandas
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

#initialize parallel-pandas
ParallelPandas.initialize(disable_pr_bar=True)

#p_apply is a parallel analog of apply method
start = time.monotonic()
res = df_exposure.p_apply(foo, raw=True, axis=1, args=(lat, lon))
print(f'parallel apply time took: {time.monotonic() - start:.1f} s.')
```

```
Out: 
     parallel apply time took: 3.7
```

This is amazing!
Total speed-up `456/3.7 ~ 120`

Comment: many thanks for the detailed explanation and various options! it helps me a lot in speeding up the computation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric` for the `haversine` distance,

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
distance = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

lat1 = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lat']
lon1 = df_exposure.loc[:, 'Lon']

lat2 = df.loc[:, 'Lat']
lon2 = df.loc[:, 'Lon']

(6371*distance.pairwise((np.array([lat1,lon1])* np.pi / 180).T, 
                    (np.array([lat2,lon2])* np.pi / 180).T).min(1))
```